# Regular expression to mask connection string password

Tags: javascript, regex

My input can be connection strings in the following formats:

```
Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Uid=username;Pwd=password;
db;username;password;
```

I need the result to be:

```
Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Uid=username;Pwd=********;
db;username;********;
```

I know the password. The password could equal another variable in the connection string. I need the number of asterisks to match the number of characters in the password.

Comment: _Hoping for a clean RegEx solution, hopefully a one line._, and what have you tried???

Comment: What if the password contains a semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this should help

```
text = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Uid=username;Pwd=password;db;username;password;";
"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Uid=username;Pwd=password;db;username;password;"
text.replace(/(Pwd=)(\w+)/,'$1********').replace(/(\w+);$/,'********')
"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Uid=username;Pwd=********;db;username;********"
```

Solution for your comment can be something like

```
text.replace(/(Pwd=)(\w+);.+;(\w+);$/,function(m,m1,m2,m3){
  return "Pwd="+ '*'.repeat(m2.length)+";db;username;"+'*'.repeat(m3.length);
})
```

Comment: Cool solution. Can you make it handle semicolons in the password and the number of asterisks to match the number of characters in the password?

Comment: Thanks Neo. I also figured out how I can get the password to my function so I now have that available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to replace the text in the string. I made the mask the same length as the password length, this is optional.

- `\b` word barrier
- `pwd=` exact match
- `([^;]+)` anything that's not a semi colon. one or more ( capture the response )
- `gim` modifiers for global, case insensitive, multiline

> changed mask functionality due to @Arthur2e5,s comment

```js
var source = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=db;Uid=username;Pwd=password;db;username;password;";
var cleaned = source.replace(/\bpwd=([^;]+)/gim, function(_, pass ){
  return 'Pwd=' + ('*'.repeat( pass.length ));
});
// one liner not much of a change
var es6oneLine = source.replace(/\bpwd=([^;]+)/gim, (_, pass) => 'Pwd=' + ('*'.repeat( pass.length )));
console.log( source );
console.log( cleaned );
console.log( es6oneLine );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

performance test of the three options. `String.prototype.repeat` wins.

```js
console.perf(function testSpeedOfLoopingAndConcatination(){
  var str = "";
  for( var ii = 0, ll = 8; ii < ll; ii++ ){
    str += '*';
  };
});

console.perf(function testSpeedOfRegexReplace(){
    var str = 'something'.replace(/./g, '*');
});

console.perf(function testSpeedOfStringProtoRepeat(){
    var str = '*'.repeat( 8 );
});
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: `ret += '*' * pass.length` and personally I believe even leaking the length is not a good idea……whatever.

Comment: I get `NaN` in chrome when multiplying a string by a Number

Comment: Grr……I must have drunk too much Python. String.prototype.repeat() should work though.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 awesome, learn't something new. will update answer

Comment: The one-liner can be changed with `repeat` too (now same efficiency!)

Comment: @Arthur2e5 sure can.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about semicolons and equal signs in the password, this could be as simple as:

```
s.replace(
  /[^;=]*;$/, 
  function(x) { return "*".repeat(x.length) + ';'; })
```